# Training LSTM using multiple sequences

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a dataset of sequences that look like the following sample. They have variable lengths, but the same number of columns. I'm interested in predicting `a(t+1)` using features `b(t), c(t), d(t), e(t) ...`

```
t  a(t)   b(t)   c(t)  d(t)  e(t)  ...
1  290.0  653.1  1.0   -0.2  -0.2  ...
2  289.9  653.2  1.0   -0.2  -0.2  ... 
3  289.9  653.2  1.0   -0.2  -0.2  ...
4  289.8  653.2  0.9   -0.2  -0.3  ...
5  289.8  653.3  0.9   -0.2  -0.3  ...
6  289.8  653.3  0.9   -0.2  -0.3  ...
...
```

I was able to prepare a single sequence for supervised learning and fit a simple LSTM model following the tutorial [found here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) using the code below. Where `train_X` includes every feature `(b,c,d,e,...)` at time `t` and `train_y` is `a(t+1)`

How do I train the model on multiple sequences? Ultimately, my goal is: given features `(b,c,d,e,...)` at `t=0, t=1, t=2, t=k-1`, predict the output `a(k+T)` for next `T` timesteps.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=1000, batch_size=1, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=1, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Your data structure is a bit confusing to me. Are `x(t+1)` and `x(t)` different sequences?  Or do you call sequence `[x(t),x(t+1),...]` or `[a(t+1),a(t),...]`?
Also, in your code, does `train_X` have the same structure as your example data?

Comment: You really need to specify your task clearly. I interpret your task as "given sequence of feature at t0, t1, t2, ..., t{k-1} predict the feature at t{k}". In addition, what is 'train_y'?

Comment: I've edited the question with more information and hopefully more clarity. @pitfall, your interpretation is right